# Jquery Cycle: pagerAnchorBuilder not working with LiveQuery

Tags: jquery, cycle

Hope u people will be fine. I am using jquery cycle plugin togther with livequery. It is working fine except pagerAnchorBuilder. Any body know how to fix this problem. Jquery Cycle Code is following:

```
            $j('ul.slider-thumbs').livequery(function() {
                $j(this).cycle({ 
                    fx:     'fade', 
                    speed:  750, 
                    timeout: 0, 
                    cleartype: true, 
                    next: '.slider-nav span.control-next a',
                    prev: '.slider-nav span.control-prev a',
                    pager:   'ul.slider-pagination',
                    pagerAnchorBuilder:     pagerFactory

                    });

        function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
            return '<li><a href="#"></a></li>';
        };      

        });
```

Comment: any chance you ever solved this? have recently come across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found your solution over at the jquery forums:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-pageranchorbuilder-not-working-with-livequery

the pager element seems to not work w/ cycle lite.  the full cycle plugin is needed for that aspect.